# Math calculation formula

Tags: math, formula

I'm trying to get to a formula that gives me a number inside a range, from a increment-able  number x that i'm giving to it.

Sure that this can be easily done with a program, inside a loop, but i want to know if is possible to archive this just by make a calculation.

For example, in this case the range is from 10-50, and if x = 10 (number to increment) and the actual position of it is 40, for example, in this case the value will be 50. Now if i give a value x of 15 i want it to give me 15, since the value 50 has been reached and the sum as to restart from 10.

Is there a solution for this case?

Thanks.

Comment: `want it to give me 15 ... as to restart from 10` Wouldn't that give you `10 + 15 = 25` instead?

Comment: No because the actual position is 40. From plus 15 You get  40 + 10 to max number 50 and then start from 10 + 5 = 15.

Comment: The way it was worded I thought you started from the last point reached before (= 50), Sounds like what you want is `pos = minpos + 1 + (pos - minpos - 1 + x) mod (maxpos - minpos)` which will keep `pos` in the range `minpos < pos <= maxpos`. This is based on your example `40 + 15 -> 15` so presumably `50 + 1 -> 11` i.e. the value `10` is skipped over.

Comment: Is this case 10 is irrelevant, but i have to keep it for reference. Thanks alot, works perfectly.